# How to rearrange data frame columns by data types sequence using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to re-arrange data frame columns by object  then follows by float64 and int

Example :

float64, float64, object, float64 , int, object

to

desire:

object , object, float64 , float64, float64, int

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can try using `pd.DataFrame.select_dtypes` with `pd.concat`:

```
pd.concat([df.select_dtypes(i) for i in ['object', 'float64', 'int']], axis=1)
```